# Looking for statistics suggestion for data set: EEG "Diagnostic" measurement comparison - non-parametric/ordinal - large proportion of zeroes

Tags: nonparametric, accuracy, zero-inflation, clinical-trials, medicine

I was hoping to get some input on handling a particular data set that falls outside of the purvue of the a lab I am apart of (usually outcomes research).

The data consists of a pair of repeated discrete measurements (1-30 seconds).  One measurement is a diagnostic tool (machine) being compared to a gold-standard (trained specialist estimations) of 30-second segments (epochs) of EEG data. They represent duration of a particular EEG signal-type (a measurement of 30 would mean the signal is persistent throughout entire 30-second segment).

There are well over 20,000 individual 30-second epochs, from 45 patient cases. The data for each patient was gathered in one time period (intra-operatively).

**Aims:**

Effectively a comparison study, the primary aim is to assess the accuracy of the diagnostic measurement against the gold-standard.

A secondary aim is to try to describe factors that may impact disagreement between the measurement, comparing measurements for each 30-sec segments as well as patient by patient (against patient char.). For epoch comparison, there is an additional binary (Yes/No) variable attached to each 30-second epoch (I plan on comparing that to the mean).

**Characteristics of the data:**

Non-normal.

Over 3/4 of the 30-second epochs are measured as 0 by both measurements. Even in cases where the signal is significantly present, it is only present in a small portion of a cases total length.  Even though a strong lack of False Pos/Neg is good, I worry these 0,0 cases can drown out meaningful observations.

**What I've Tried/Am considering:**

***Aim 1: Accuracy of diagnostic vs gold-standard***
Epoch by Epoch Analysis:
Proportion of Epochs where the diagnostic test is within X% of the gold standard.

Bland-Altman - The plot isn't that useful as the values are discreet (whole seconds)

Kendall's Tau - Modification that returns: 
Probability of: two diagnostic values are within x seconds => their paired gold standard are within x seconds.

**Aim 2: *Factors impacting disagreement***

Separating patients into quartiles by certain factors - Age, Surgery Length.
I also will Separate the patients into 2 groups by surgery position (Prone/Supine).

**Thanks!**

This is my first time on stack exchange.

Hopefully this was a concise enough explanation. This is a side project of mine (I'm a CRC), which has been on the back burner, and have sort of hit a wall. A diagnostic comparison study is not typically what my lab does (outcomes research). Ideally this will be aimed towards a clinical audience - so ideally looking for commonly used or at least easily describable statistical analysis.

I'm handy with matlab - and can implement a stat analysis so long as I've got an algorithm.

I'm essentially just looking for stats test that stand out to anyone knowledgeable in this area. Thank you to those that take the time to consider my question(s).

Comment: Welcome to the site. I don't really understand the nature of your data, mostly because I don't understand your second paragraph.  What is diagnostic and gold standard?

Comment: Oh sorry, there was a typo when copying it over.  Ill try to address it, thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried to clarify my questions, I used diagnostic vs gold-standard as it seems common language when comparing a measurement tool against a reliable source (Eg. MRI estimation of tumor size vs actual size of tumor measured directly during surgery).  In short, I'm comparing paired estimations (in seconds - out of 30) where one is the tool being assessed against a gold-standard (the measurement assumed to be a reliable estimation).  I want to comment on the accuracy of the diagnostic tool against the gold-standard measurement, the correlation of certain factors with that disagreement.